# Remove a duplicate word sentence in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Given a problem that determines the output of the word, length of each word, and the number of times the word repeats, I have the following code capable to determine the word and length of each word below:

```
String sentence;
String charSentence;
String[] wordOutput;

private void analyzeWords(String s) {
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    wordOutput = new String[words.length];
    int[] repeats = new int[words.length];

    // Increment a single repeat
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        repeats[i] = 1;

        // Increment when repeated.
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length - 1; j++) {
            if (words[i].equalsIgnoreCase(words[j])) {
                repeats[i]++;
            }
        }

        wordOutput[i] = words[i] + "\t" + words[i].length() + "\t" + repeats[i];
    }
```

When I run the program, I get the following output:

```
Equal   5   2
Equal   5   1 <- This is a duplicate word and should not be here when it repeats.
```

Does anyone know where my problem is? Is it something relating that deals with my repeats array?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a `HashMap`? If so I would use this to record the word as the key and the number of occurrences as the value

Comment: I am not allowed to use `HashMap` as the problem doesn't require it.

Comment: One problem is that you set `j` to `i+1`, and then loop while it is less than the length minus one. You need to loop until the length. Next, you'll need some way to keep track of if a word has already occurred in the `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that in the inner for loop you are looping from `i+1` to `length-1`. You need to loop till `length`. Second you will need to determine if there are any occurrences of the word in the `String`, and if so use a `continue` statement. You can do:

```
outer:
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

    repeats[i] = 1;
    for(int index = i-1; index >= 0; index--) {
        if(words[i].equals(words[index])) {
            continue outer;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

However the problem with this is that there will be `null` values at the end of the list, as you specify an `Array` with the same length as the number of words. To solve this you can do:

```
 wordOutput = Arrays.stream(wordOutput).filter(e-> e!= null).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Which will filter out the `null` values

***Output:***

(With the input `String`: `"This is a String is a with a lot lot of this repeats repeats"`)

```
This    4   2
is      2   2
a       1   3
String  6   1
with    4   1
lot     3   2
of      2   1
this    4   1
repeats 7   2
```

Comment: Can add more information about this? I don't quite still get the output to work but everything else is fine. I am getting a logic error in Eclipse saying: `Detail formatter error: Evaluations must contain either an expression or a block of well-formed statements` on wordOutput within the debugger.

Comment: @RodArgumedo On which line is the warning on? And what output do you get?

Comment: @RodArgumedo Also just a note, you pass a `String` (`s`) but you never use it. Did you mean to have `String[] words = s.split(" ");`?

Comment: Yes, to determine the word without having whitespace in the array.

Comment: It doesn't return anything when I got the output of each word.

Comment: @RodArgumedo Yes but at the moment you have `sentence.split(" ");`. This makes it so that the `String` you pass in is never used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183085/discussion-between-rod-argumedo-and-gblodgett).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of incrementing count at all index store the count only in last occurence of word, in other case, have the count value of 0. at the end traverse the count array, if its greater than zero, print the value and its count

```
private void analyzeWords(String s) {
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    wordOutput = new String[words.length];
    int[] repeats = new int[words.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        int count =1;
        int index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length - 1; j++) {
            if (words[i].equalsIgnoreCase(words[j])) {
                count++;
                index = j;
            }
        }
        if(repeats[index]==0){
          repeats[index]=count; // update repeat array only for last occurence of word
          wordOutput[i] = words[i] + "\t" + words[i].length() + "\t" + repeats[index];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as GBlodgett mention you should check all left words for repeats, your current solution skips last word. Update second loop termination condition to `j < words.length`.

Second, if you want to print duplicates only once you need a condition in your solution. One of the example:

```
boolean[] duplicates = new boolean[words.length];
// Increment a single repeat
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    repeats[i] = 1;
    // Check for duplicates,
    // If the word was not marked as duplicate
    if (!duplicates[i]) {
        // Increment when repeated.
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            if (words[i].equalsIgnoreCase(words[j])) {
                repeats[i]++;
                duplicates[j] = true;
            }
        }
        wordOutput[i] = words[i] + "\t" + words[i].length() + "\t" + repeats[i];
    }
}
```

---

There is a Java 8+ solution, for example:

```
Map<String, Long> m = Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Map will have pairs of word and it occurrences.

Comment: This solution works. However, you are returning the second string array object that would return as `null` on the repeated word and I don't want to expect that output.